# C# WebBrowser open new window and keep javascript object

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to design a multiple tab browser with webbrowser-control,

when my webrowser invoke the following javascript.

```
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank");
    // The website need do something to get url
    myWindow.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
}
```

my webbrowser fire newWindow event first, 
then i will open a new webbrowser,

in this case the url is "about:blank",

but the problem is how to bring "myWindow" to the new webbrowser and navigate to the correct url.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use _parent instead of _blank in window.open.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't modify "myFunction", I get "myFunction" from the website which I visit and find out this problem.